# how to edit this php script ? if file exist show this , if not show another?

Tags: php, ajax

i need to edit this script to show another part of page if the file .xls does not exist . for example $found = false , show flashexit.php

```
    <?
     $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     $sec = "30";
     $find = '/flash/file/FLASH.xls'; //The file to find
     $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
     $found = false;
     foreach($paths as $p) {
       $fullname = $p.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$find;
       if(is_file($fullname)) {
         $found = $fullname;
         include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/inc/flashnewblu.inc.php");
         break;
       }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Please explain yourself better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need is to check this [link](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). Is related to the function `file_exists`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a file exists with the built-in function [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

```
<?php
 $find = '/flash/file/FLASH.xls'; //The file to find
 $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
 $found = false;
 foreach($paths as $p) {
   $fullname = $p.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$find;
   if(file_exists($fullname)) {
     $found = $fullname;
     include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/inc/flashnewblu.inc.php");
     break;
   }
}
if(!$found) {
    echo 'File '.$fullname.' doesn\'t exists. Make a redirection to flashexit.php';
}
?>
```